# Hive Managed table - Filename

Tags: hive

In hive managed tables is there anyway to input/specify the filename for the data files getting created?

For example, the below data file ends with "000000_0", is it possible to get that file generated with specific name?

hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/orders_partitioned/order_month=Apr/000000_0

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the file name when you input the data using hive cli or sqoop. But there is a way to input the specified file using copy command

```
hadoop fs -cp <src_file> <dest_folder>
```

In this case you have to be careful the data in this source file is to be matched exactly with the partition condition of destination directory.